# navigateUp() and popBackStack() not working. Instead, they reload the current fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am trying to navigate up the backstack. On calling the method `view?.findNavController().navigateUp()` and logging the destination using `view?.findNavController().getCurrentDestination()`, I see the function popping the current destination and then reloading it again. I don't understand why this could be happening yet I am doing the same in other fragments and it's working.

Comment: One possibility is that you are going to the previous fragment but then that fragment again asks navController to navigate to the next fragment. Are you using LiveData to trigger navigation?

Comment: For better debugging, you can use a NavController.onDestinationChangedListener in your parent activity to monitor changes in you navigation back stack.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, you are right. That is exactly what was happening. On navigating up, the fragment was asking to navigate into the fragment again because I am using LiveData to trigger the navigation. To solve the issue, I am updating the MutableLiveData, which updates the LiveData then navigating. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue came up because I was using LiveData to trigger the navigation. To avoid the issue, I have had to update the MutableLiveData before navigating so that it does not request to navigate back when I navigateUp from the destination.